# Is there a way to set a counter in a mustache iteration?

Tags: mustache

I have a code that renders a mustache template with some iterations like:

```
{{#items}}
  some html code....
{{/items}}
```

but I want to place into the iteration the number of item that is rendered, like that:

```
{{#items}}
  This is the item [COUNTER-VAR]
{{/items}}
```

There is some way to perform this..??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Mustache, How to get the index of the current Section](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021495/in-mustache-how-to-get-the-index-of-the-current-section)

Answer (score 16):

Handlebars no longer necessary. You can use the high order sections in current mustache. These basically let you call a function with the contents of the section as an argument. If that section is inside an iteration it will be called for each item in an iteration.

Given this template (kept in a script tag for convenience & clarity)

```
<script type="text/html" id="itemview">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
        <tbody>
            {{#items}}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{#count}}unused{{/count}}</td>
                    <td>{{.}}</td
                </tr>
            {{/items}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</script>
```

...and the following code, you can build a numbered list.

```
function buildPage(root)
{
    var counter = 0;
    var data = {
        'items': [ 'England', 'Germany', 'France' ],

        'count' : function () {
            return function (text, render) {
                // note that counter is in the enclosing scope
                return counter++;
            }
        }
    };

    // fetch the template from the above script tag
    var template = document.getElementById('itemview').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
}
```

Output:
    0     England
    1     Germany
    2     France

Answer (score 7):

Use {{@index}} inside iteration.

```
{{#data}}
    <p>Index is {{@index}}</p>
{{/data}}
```

Comment: This method does not work if using pure `Mustache`. I believe this has either always been a `Handlebar` exclusive feature, or has been removed from pure `Mustache` for at least five years now.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively just add a counter to your array... I understand this is an ugly solution but it's the most readable and gets the job done.

```js
const myData = ["Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo"];

const tags = {};
tags.myArr = myData.map((data, index) => ({index, data}));

return Mustache.render(template, tags);
```

```
{{#myArr}}
  Number {{index}}: {{data}}
{{/myArr}}
```

Answer (score -1):

you could use the handlebars extension to mustache and write a helper function that bumps a counter.

I put more explanation here.
[In Mustache, How to get the index of the current Section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021495/in-mustache-how-to-get-the-index-of-the-current-section/5073396#5073396)

Comment: That doesn't help much.