# Index of an array element in Mustache.js

Tags: javascript, iterator, mustache

This is what I'd like to do in Mustache.js but not seeing how with the documentation.

```
var view = {items:['Mercury','Venus','Earth','Mars']};
var template = "<ul> {{#items}}<li>{{i}} - {{.}}</li>{{/items}} </ul>";
var html = Mustache.to_html(template,view);
```

Desired output:

```
<ul>
  <li>0 - Mercury</li>
  <li>1 - Venus</li>
  <li>2 - Earth</li>
  <li>3 - Mars</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can't.  You either have to pass an object containing the id and value, or inject the value post-processing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### An alternative solution, without fooling around with Mustache.js

Instead of fooling around with mustache you might as well use a `<ol></ol>` instead of `<ul></ul>`, that will prefix each item with `index+1`.

*If you'd like you can use css to change the starting number to 0, and it will render exactly as you want. You can even change the `dot` after the number, to something such as `" - "`, and problem is solved.*

```
<ol>
  <li>Mercury</li>
  <li>Venus</li>
  <li>Earth</li>
  <li>Mars</li>
</ol>
```

the above will render as:

```
1. Mercury
2. Venus
3. Earth
4. Mars
```

---

### the Mustache.js way to do it

The proper method if you'd like to do it in mustache is to convert your array of strings to an array of objects, where index and string value is present.

```
// I wrote this from the back of my head, it's untested and not guaranteed
// to work without modifications, though the theory behind it is valid.


var array     = ["123","stackoverflow","abc"];
var obj_array = [];

for (idx in array)
   obj_array.push ({'index': idx, 'str': array[idx]});

var view     = {items: obj_array};
var template = "<ul>{{#items}}<li>{{index}} - {{str}}</li>{{/items}}</ul>";
var html     = Mustache.to_html(template,view);
```

Comment: Yeah, I think the <ol> method would be good in many cases but my specific need is a little more complex.

Comment: I was afraid explicitly adding an index to the view object might be the answer...too bad. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Dane I edited my post and wrote a sample implementation, if you try it out please get back to me so I can alter it if it doesn't work, or remove the comment saying that it maybe won't work, if it works.

Comment: I'm sure your answer works. I was just hoping there was a way to get the idx without explicitly adding it to the view object. Maybe this will be part of Mustache 2. Thanks again for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 21):

Looking for a fast clean solution?

### Simply add an `index` function

```
var data = {
    items: [{
            name: Aliasghar
            , grade: 19
        }, {
            name: Afagh
            , grade: 20
    }]
    , index: function() {
        return ++window['INDEX']||(window['INDEX']=0);
    }
}
```

and your template could be like this:

```
{{#items}}
    {{index}} -- {{name}} is {{grade}}
{{/items}}
```

---

### How it works

We add a `index: function(){}` to data and we use it as a normal function in template.
This function adds a key to the `window` object which is available globally; then increases it one by one.

### To use with multiple lists

Please note that if you are using multiple templates one after another you need to either reset `window['INDEX']` or change it's key to something else like `window['YEKI_DIGE']`.
Another way of doing this is by adding a `resetIndex` function. Here is the way:

```
var data = {
    items: [{
            name: Aliasghar
            , grade: 19
        }, {
            name: Afagh
            , grade: 20
    }]
    , index: function() {
        return ++window['INDEX']||(window['INDEX']=0);
    }
    , resetIndex: function() {
        window['INDEX']=null;
        return;
    }
}
```

and your template could be like this:

```
{{#items}}
    {{index}} -- {{name}} is {{grade}}
{{/items}}
{{resetIndex}}
```

Inspired by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10208239/257479 from [dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/310359/dave) on [In Mustache, How to get the index of the current Section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021495)

Answer (score 4):

If you can use handlebars.js, then you can use the partial mentioned in this gist:
https://gist.github.com/1048968

Ref: [In Mustache, How to get the index of the current Section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021495/in-mustache-how-to-get-the-index-of-the-current-section)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to access the index multiple times per item, I would suggest something like the following.

```
var data = {
    items: [{
        name: Aliasghar
        , grade: 19
    }, {
        name: Afagh
        , grade: 20
    }]
    , setUpIndex: function() {
        ++window['INDEX']||(window['INDEX']=0);
        return;
    }
    , getIndex: function() {
        return window['INDEX'];
    }
    , resetIndex: function() {
        window['INDEX']=null;
        return;
    }
}
```

- Use the `restIndex` function before iterating each list in Mustache.
- Use the `setUpIndex` function at the start of each list item to set up the index for that item.
- Use the `getIndex` item to access the index.

As an example, consider this.

```
{{resetIndex}}
{{#items}}
    {{setUpIndex}}
    {{getIndex}}. {{name}} is at index {{getIndex}}
{{/items}}
```

Notice how you can access index more than once per item without getting the wrong value.

Comment: in setUpIndex:: , should the return statement in the next line ? else the index values will get printed while rendering the mustache template.

Answer (score 1):

(Tested in node 4.4.7, moustache 2.2.1.)

If you want a nice clean functional way to do it, that doesn't involve global variables or mutating the objects themselves, use this function;

```
var withIds = function(list, propertyName, firstIndex) {
    firstIndex |= 0;
    return list.map( (item, idx) => {
        var augmented = Object.create(item);
        augmented[propertyName] = idx + firstIndex;
        return augmented;
    })
};
```

Use it when you're assembling your view;

```
var view = {
    peopleWithIds: withIds(people, 'id', 1) // add 'id' property to all people, starting at index 1
};
```

The neat thing about this approach is that it creates a new set of 'viewmodel' objects, using the old set as prototypes. You can read the `person.id` just as you would read `person.firstName`. However, this function doesn't change your people objects at all, so other code (which might have relied on the ID property not being there) will not be affected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Handlerbars.js, then

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("inc", function (value, options) {
    return parseInt(value) + 1;
});
```

To use it in HTML

```
{{inc @@index}}
```