# Mustache.js each loop not working

Tags: javascript, mustache

My mustache template is not rendering and I don't understand why not.

```
var output = Mustache.render('{{#languages}} {{@index}} {{locale}} {{/languages}}', '{"languages" : [ { "locale" : "english", "code" : "en" }, { "locale" : "deutsch", "code" : "de" }, { "locale" : "español", "code" : "es" }, { "locale" : "français", "code" : "fr" } ]}');
```

This output is empty. I also want the index to be rendered with each item.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fuzzyvagina/a40yyvfa/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first issue is that you should pass an Object as your data, not a string. Remove the quotes from around your `languages` object.

The second issue is that Mustache does not support the `{{@index}}` special reference. Many Mustache-like templating systems such as [Dust.js](http://www.dustjs.com) and [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com) do intrinsically support this, but in Mustache you'll have to write a helper and include it in your data. To do that, see one of the many other StackOverflow answers on the topic, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19693610/938516).

Answer (score 1):

For one thing you're passing a string instead of an object as the 2nd argument.

Answer (score 1):

Second parameter in Mustache.render() is object. you have passed a string

```
Mustache.render('{{#languages}} {{@index}} {{locale}} {{/languages}}',  {"languages" : [ { "locale" : "english", "code" : "en" }, { "locale" : "deutsch", "code" : "de" }, { "locale" : "español", "code" : "es" }, { "locale" : "français", "code" : "fr" }, { "locale" : "italiano", "code" : "it" }, { "locale" : "português (Portugal)", "code" : "ptpt" }, { "locale" : "português (Brasil)", "code" : "prbr" }, { "locale" : "Norsk", "code" : "no" }, { "locale" : "日本語", "code" : "jp" }, { "locale" : "中文", "code" : "cn" }, { "locale" : "Русский язык", "code" : "ru" } ]} );
```