# Mustache.js is adding text instead of html

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, mustache

It's my first time when I use [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) and need some help, please.

Doing a html template builder and I am trying to grab data from JSON and HTML files, than show them into my page.

So I am using this script to get Default theme from JSON than to get the HTML:

```
$.getJSON('templates.json', function(json){
    $.each(json, function(theme, val){
        if(theme == 'Default'){
            template.load('templates/'+val.url+'/template.html', function(response, status, xhr){
                $(this).html(Mustache.render($(this).html(), {
                    tabs:val.tabs
                }));
            });
        }
    });
});
```

JSON:

```
{ 
    "Default" : {
        "url":"default",
        "logo": "YOUR LOGO HERE",
        "phone": "+1234567890",
        "tabs": [
            "About Us",
            "Delivery", 
            "Payment", 
            "Shipping", 
            "Contact Us"
        ]
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
    {{#tabs.length}}
    <div id="tabs">
        {{#tabs}}
        <input class="state" type="radio" title="tab1" name="tabs-state" id="tab1" checked />
        {{/tabs}}
        <div class="tabs flex-tabs">
            {{#tabs}}
            <label for="tab1" id="tab1-label" class="tab">{{.}}</label>
            {{/tabs}}
            {{#tabs}}
            <div id="tab1-panel" class="panel active">[[{{.}}]]</div>
            {{#tabs}}
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/tabs.length}}
```

I just can't display the tabs. First time I tried with javascript to convert json into html, but Mustache was showing text instead of html. Now I am trying with conditions in html with no luck.

I also need to add numbers to each item, eg: "tab1", "tab2".. - is this `{{@index}}` good for that?

How can I add `checked` only for first items?

Also not sure if `{{.}}` this is displaying the name of my tab..

Answer (score 1):

You've almost got this nailed, although have slightly misunderstood how to write the `mustacheJS` view. It's even simpler than you thought! See below. I've simplified the example, so you understand the concept.

Some explanation for below:

`{{#Default}}{/Default}}` represents looping over an object literal

`{{#tabs}}{{/tabs}}` presents looping over the object that exists within `{{#Defaults}}`.

`{{.}}` displays the entire contents of the object. If this was a complex object, it would be rendered as `[object][object]`. If you ever encounter this, you must name the object explicitly in your view.

```
<div class="tabs">
{{#Default}}
   {{#tabs}}
         <input class="state" type="radio" title="Tab1" name="tabs-state" checked/>
         <div class=tabs flex-tabs>
            {{.}}
         </div>
   {{/tabs}}
{{/Default}}
</div>
```

**View Produced**

```
<div class="tabs">
   <div class=tabs flex-tabs>
      About Us
   </div>
   <div class=tabs flex-tabs>
      Delivery
   </div>
   <div class=tabs flex-tabs>
      Payment
   </div>
   <div class=tabs flex-tabs>
      Shipping
   </div>
   <div class=tabs flex-tabs>
      Contact Us
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: any idee of how can I add 1,2,3,4 (index) to each div? without adding them manually into json

Comment: I usually add an index to my object. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567413/index-of-an-array-element-in-mustache-js). I believe handlebars allows you to access index from view, but I've never done this.

Comment: yup, but I can't use it in `JSON` :(