# Getting the index when iterating with amp-mustache

Tags: amp-html, amp-mustache

How do you get the index of the current element for a given iteration when using amp-mustache?

I would expect it to look something like this:

```xml
{{#thing}}
<p>
    Thing #{{index}}
</p>
\{{/thing}}
```

but that doesn't seem to work...

Is this even possible?

Comment: share your json code, how its look

Comment: As I understand it `amp-mustache` is logic-less and you can't really get index. But you can try [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567413/index-of-an-array-element-in-mustache-js)

Answer (score 1):

As I know we can't. But you can add index into the JSON reponse