# Get index for Mustache loop in Java

Tags: java, mustache

I am trying to access the index of a loop, while displaying the elements of a Collection.

```
{{#attachments}}
  <div>Returns the whole Attachment object: {{this}}</div>
  <div>Is a property of the Attachment class: {{fileName}}</div>
{{/attachments}}
```

With `{{this}}` I can access the whole object `Attachment [id=24fileName=image002.jpg, hash=E+Rasjhdgsajh=, signed=false]`, which does not really help.

I understood that Mustache.js apparently supports indexes with `{#index}` [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021495/in-mustache-how-to-get-the-index-of-the-current-section).

In Mustache.java something like that was proposed, but not implemented, because it would encourage poor separation between the template and the data. cf. [Support for array item by index](https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java/issues/151).

[Sam Pullara](https://github.com/spullara) suggested to use this [workaround](https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java/blob/master/compiler/src/test/java/com/github/mustachejava/ArraysIndexesTest.java), which I unfortunately can't really make sense of.

I am now considering adding a field to my `Attachment` class representing an index, but would like to know if there is another way to deal with this problem.

The [Javadocs Mustache](http://mustachejava.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/apidocs/index.html) unfortunately, don't seam to exist yet.

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are these the javadocs you're looking for?  http://spullara.github.io/mustache/apidocs/

Comment: Thank you! I clicked the link on Github!